# Destructor for primitive type dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management, destructor

If I want to delete a dynamically allocated array of primitive type values:

`int *it = new int[10]`

do I just put `delete [] it` in the destructor to take care of releasing memory properly?

OR

Realizing that, as a pointer is a primitive type, does deleting a dynamically allocated array involve doing something like this in the destructor:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx != 5; ++idx)
        delete sp[idx];
    delete[] sp;
```

I'm rather confused about this as I am having a lot of memory related errors in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have:

```
int* it = new int[10];
```

the correct way to `delete` it is:

```
delete[] it;
```

If you have a member variable of this type you need to implement a copy constructor and assignment operator as the default versions of these are not sufficient or make the class uncopyable.

As this is C++ I would suggest using `std::vector<int>` instead as this will handle the memory management for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `new` and `delete`, the general rule to follow is this: Use exactly as many `delete`s as you did `new`s.

In your case, you invoked `new[]` only once. You should inovke `delete[]` only once.

As an aside, if you ever store a pointer in a member variable, please consider the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

I say "If you are going to use `new` and `delete`", because you often shouldn't. Using RAII techniques, and standard containers, it is entirely possible to write perfectly useful programs that never directly invoke `new` or `delete`.

If you are trying to maintain an array of `int`s, use `std::vector`:

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> it;

    void SomeFun() { it.resize(10); }
};
```

Then, in your destructor, *do nothing*. Vectors disappear with no help from you at all.